# DataFrame Pandas - Aplicar o groupby de uma coluna a outras linhas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Olá, tenho um dataframe com uma coluna 'Time' e outras 6 colunas. Eu preciso apenas dos dados baseados nos valores duplicados de 'Time'. Assim, já usei o groupby e criei a coluna "Pico" que é onde os valores se repetem. Contudo, eu queria separar agora as outras 6 colunas baseadas nela. Exemplo, ficar com a linha 1421 e 1422 toda. Alguém? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*EDIT Consegui o que eu queria utilizando: df[(df['Repetidos']==2)]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
No caso, eu consigo ver o horizonte todo das valores repetidos baseados no 'Time'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta filtrar os elementos não nulos da coluna 'Pico', dessa forma:

```
df = df[df['Pico'].notnull()]
```

EDIT: Caso seja necessário apenas filtrar os valores repetidos, sem nenhum outro tipo de operação envolvida, é possível também usar a função `duplicated` do dataframe com `keep=False` mantendo todas as repetições, assim:

```py
df = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Comment: Oi, eu consegui fazer o que eu queria mas utilizando:  limpa = df[(df['Repetidos']==2)] , e aí consegui visualizar o horizonte todo apenas das que eram igual a 2, incluindo todas as outras colunas. O problema de filtrar os valores repetidos apenas das outras colunas é que existem "valores repetidos" que não eram para se repetir, e eu acabava tendo problemas, digamos que meu termômetro de seleção de dados repetidos eram o do 'Time' apenas. De qualquer forma, MUITO OBRIGADA!